# Making a background image in css won't work

Tags: html, css

I am making a website in HTML and CSS and I am trying to include and image, but the image won't appear. This is what I have done:

The HTML part:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<div class = "top-links">
<li><a href="index.html">Home page</a></li>
<li><a href="about us.html">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="our songs.html">Our songs</a></li>
<li><a href="see us play.html">See us play</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
<li><a href="playing a concert.html">Playing a concert</a></li>
</div>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS part:

```
.top-links {
border-style: hidden; 
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.5em;
background-image: url("images/cricket bat and ball.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<div>` as a child of a `<ul>`. I'd also recommend removing the spaces in your image's file name, possibly replacing them with underscores or dashes.

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Comment: I have a folder called website, then inside it I have all the HTML files and two other folders one for images, the other for CSS

Comment: Spaces in an images name still work I tried adding another image elsewhere that had spaces in its name and it was fine

Comment: What does your browser's console say? Do you see any errors in DevTools?

Comment: @ j08691 how would i do it then?

Comment: It displays everything else fine if thats what you mean

Comment: removing the spaces has no effect, just tried it

Comment: @Qwertykey Go to DevTools (in chrome it's `Ctrl+Shift+I`) and check console for errors

Comment: in console there is the error file not found (the image file i was trying to put in)

Comment: @Qwertykey Does it show where it tried to find the image?

Comment: I found a makeshift solution that works, I uploaded it to imgur and used the link instead

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the image URL in the CSS has spaces in it. Try renaming the image to something without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few errors with your code, the first was an issue with this line

```
<div class = "top-links">
```

You shouldn't have the spaces between the equals sign - this may work with some browsers but isn't good practise so it may have turned out that your styling was simply not being picked up. So I changed it to this

```
<div class="top-links">
```

Next problem was similar but this time with your CSS

```
background-image: url("images/cricket bat and ball.jpg");
```

You can't have spaces in an image URL ... well you can but again it leaves you open to all sorts of issues and is again considered bad practise, I would rename your image something like **cricket-bat-and-ball.jpg** so I changed that line to this

```
background-image: url("images/cricket-bat-and-ball.jpg");
```

And that should fix your errors - I put the whole thing together in to a fiddle to test and it seems to work fine, I replaced the image URL with a placeholder image, the background image is now being picked up

https://jsfiddle.net/xjerfnLd/

Comment: this still doesn't work... I had look at the developer editor thing you get online and in console there is the error file not found

Comment: Sounds like the link to your file is incorrect - this could be because it has spaces in the image name as I explained, did you try renaming your image file?

Comment: Firstly try replacing your background image line of CSS with mine from the fiddle

This should resemble the fiddle - this proves your CSS is correct and your HTML is correct, the only thing that can be wrong is the image - either the link to it or the image itself, try opening the image in Chrome or Windows Explorer or Finder if you're on a Mac - does the image work? Does the URL match what you have in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top-links {
border-style: hidden; 
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.5em;
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/uYImr7U.jpg");
/*background-image: url("images/cricket_bat_and_ball.jpg");*/
background-size:cover;
background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<div class = "top-links">
<ul>

<li><a href="index.html">Home page</a></li>
<li><a href="about us.html">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="our songs.html">Our songs</a></li>
<li><a href="see us play.html">See us play</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="merchandise.html">Merchandise</a></li>
<li><a href="playing a concert.html">Playing a concert</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

It works fine for me.

Kindly check the image path that you have given. 
Is it correct?

Hope this helps.